# Encryption for Google Documents

Tags: google-drive, encryption

How can I encrypt the HTTP messages that implement the Google Documents web application?

I am concerned about the security risk of editing and storing private documents on Google Documents.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant using a secure connection ( SSL ) then you could use https. Just go to https://docs.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested you can try [SafeGDocs](http://www.safegdocs.com), a free add-on for Firefox that encrypts and decrypts Google Docs documents.